# sandeep shetty/shopify_api directory isnt built in symfony folder

Tags: php, symfony, shopify

i am just begineer and dont know about symphony.
i have  added symfony on my localhost. now i want to integrate it with shopify_api. 
i have followed instructions given in github https://github.com/sandeepshetty/shopify_api but as they said

**Install Composer:**

```
$ curl -s http://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

**Run the install command:**

```
$ php composer.phar install
```

This will download shopify_api into the vendor/sandeepshetty/shopify_api directory.

BUT THERE IS NO FOLDER OF SHOPIFY_API IN MY DIRECTORY STRUCTURE.
and i am not getting any exception in my command prompt.... please tell me the steps how can i integrate with shopify... i want to develop shopify app with symfony framework

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot to do the first step in [shopify doc](https://github.com/sandeepshetty/shopify_api#download-via-composer) (adding the shopify bundle to the require).

Please follow all the steps in that documentation.

Answer (score 0):

At the root of symofny project folder ,  there is a  composer.json  open it  , i added in the below of doctrine

> "require": {
>           "php": ">=5.3.3",
>           "symfony/symfony": "2.1.*",
>           "doctrine/orm": ">=2.2.3,<2.4-dev",
>           "sandeepshetty/shopify_api": "dev-master"
>       },

now run update composer command .